# Print a long iframe content in current page using javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a web page surrounding an iframe from another website. I need to add a button in the parent window to print content of the iframe. Below is my print code, very simple:

```
//Function to print Web Part
        function PrintIframe()
        {
            if (window.frames[frameName].innerHTML != "") {
                    window.frames[frameName].focus();
                    window.frames[frameName].print();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(PrintIframe,1000);
                } 
        }
```

The problem is, the height of iframe is much longer than window's height. So the print result only contains first page with vertical scroll bar on the right. But the iframe has no scroll bar, the parent window has. I need to print the whole content of the iframe with multiple pages. How can it be done? I can fully control pages of the two web sites. 
Thanks.

Comment: do you want to print only the iframes content or the parents pages content including the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resource here that basically suggests using a "print.css" file that will format your web page for printing to a printer:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=162465

the suggestions here are to remove float:left and float:rights, as well as increase the height.